LLDB how to add symbol files at certain address?
In GDB you can do add-symbol-file <library> <address> to load symbols files at a particular address. What's the equivalent in LLDB?
I have already tried
image add <symbol file>
target modules load --file <symbol file> .text <address>

but this doesn't seem to fix the unknown symbols

Those are the correct commands.  That feature gets used heavily for analyzing crash reports and the like, so it should also work for what you're trying to do.  To diagnose your issue, we'll need to see specifically the steps you are taking and on what kind of binary, etc.  Might be more appropriate to file a report with the lldb issues site:
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues

The commands were correct, it turns out I was just missing additional symbols.
I was able to work out the missing symbol file though looking at cat /proc/$(pidof <my_program>)/maps | grep xp | grep <first 5-7 characters of the missing address>
Then I loaded them in as normal
image add <missing symbol file>
target modules load --file <symbol file> .text 0x<address>

